# Understanding Preferences in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, preferences, geometryreader

iOS 15 Swift 5.5 Trying to understand preferences, but struggling with GeometryReader

I crafted this code reading a tutorial, but it doesn't work correctly. The green box should appear over the red dot, the first one. But it is over the centre one. When I tap on the dot, it moves to the third...it feels like SwiftUI drew the whole thing and then changed its mind about the coordinates. Sure I could change the offsets, but that is a hack. Surely SwiftUI should be updating the preferences if the thing moves.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var activeIdx: Int = 0
@State private var rects: [CGRect] = Array<CGRect>(repeating: CGRect(), count: 12)
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke(lineWidth: 3.0).foregroundColor(Color.green)
            .frame(width: rects[activeIdx].size.width, height: rects[activeIdx].size.height)
            .offset(x: rects[activeIdx].minX, y: rects[activeIdx].minY)
        HStack {
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 0)
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 1)
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 2)
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: rects)
    }.onPreferenceChange(MyTextPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
        for p in preferences {
            self.rects[p.viewIdx] = p.rect
            print("p \(p)")
        }
    }.coordinateSpace(name: "myZstack")
}
}

struct SubtleView: View {
@Binding var activeIdx:Int
let idx: Int
var body: some View {
    Circle()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
        .background(MyPreferenceViewSetter(idx: idx))
        .onTapGesture {
            activeIdx = idx
        }
}
}

struct MyTextPreferenceData: Equatable {
let viewIdx: Int
let rect: CGRect
}

struct MyTextPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
typealias Value = [MyTextPreferenceData]

static var defaultValue: [MyTextPreferenceData] = []

static func reduce(value: inout [MyTextPreferenceData], nextValue: () -> [MyTextPreferenceData]) {
    value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
}
}

struct MyPreferenceViewSetter: View {
let idx: Int

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.clear)
            .preference(key: MyTextPreferenceKey.self,
                        value: [MyTextPreferenceData(viewIdx: self.idx, rect: geometry.frame(in: .named("myZstack")))])
    }
}
}
```

Tried moving the onPreferences up a level, down a level..attaching it to each view... but still doesn't update...what did I miss here=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `offset(x:y:)` instead of `position(x:y:)`.

Your `ZStack`'s coordinates will start from the top-left which will (locally) be `(0, 0)`. However, by default the green square will be centered between all 3 red circles. This causes a problem because the coordinates start at `(0, 0)` but the square starts centered (i.e. one square off).

Initially you have the first circle starting at `(0, 0)` but you are already have a centered square, so the offset is `0` in both `x` and `y`, therefore already centered and it appears like you are on a different index.

Fix this by replacing with `position(x:y:)` and by measuring the mid points:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke(lineWidth: 3.0).foregroundColor(Color.green)
    .frame(width: rects[activeIdx].size.width, height: rects[activeIdx].size.height)
    .position(x: rects[activeIdx].midX, y: rects[activeIdx].midY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You read absolute coordinates in preference so need to use `position` instead of offset

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke(lineWidth: 3.0).foregroundColor(Color.green)
    .frame(width: rects[activeIdx].size.width, height: rects[activeIdx].size.height)
    .position(x: rects[activeIdx].midX, y: rects[activeIdx].midY)  // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

And here is complete fixed body:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HStack {
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 0)
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 1)
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 2)
        }
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke(lineWidth: 3.0).foregroundColor(Color.green)
            .frame(width: rects[activeIdx].size.width, height: rects[activeIdx].size.height)
            .position(x: rects[activeIdx].midX, y: rects[activeIdx].midY)
    }.onPreferenceChange(MyTextPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
        for p in preferences {
            self.rects[p.viewIdx] = p.rect
            print("p \(p)")
        }
    }.coordinateSpace(name: "myZstack")
    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: activeIdx)
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi it was a 50/50 between you and George; and given he has just 17K against your 156k I thought it fair to give it to him this time. He did beat you to the post too it seems.

Comment: @user3069232 I think I was a few minutes behind. I was writing an explanation, and after submitting an answer on Stack Overflow, it then loaded Asperi's answer too. I thought it was worth keeping because of the explanation though because I don't want to duplicate already-existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is simply that a `ZStack` is naturally center aligned, so your initial position, before the offset is over the second circle, but your `activeIdx` is 0 which is the first circle. If you view it on the Canvas in the static preview. Simply changing the `ZStack` alignment to `.leading` lines everything up.

[image: Gif of result]

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) { // Set your alignment here
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke(lineWidth: 3.0).foregroundColor(Color.green)
            .frame(width: rects[activeIdx].size.width, height: rects[activeIdx].size.height)
            .offset(x: rects[activeIdx].minX, y: rects[activeIdx].minY)
        HStack {
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 0)
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 1)
            SubtleView(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 2)
        }
        // Also change the animation value to activeIdx
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: activeIdx)
    }.onPreferenceChange(MyTextPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
        for p in preferences {
            self.rects[p.viewIdx] = p.rect
            print("p \(p)")
        }
    }.coordinateSpace(name: "myZstack")
}
```

Comment: Ytb although I accepted the other answer. I wanted to say this was an excellent one too! Sorry I cannot accept more than one.

Comment: They all work. We can address this issue in many ways in SwiftUI. Also, while you were asking specifically about `PreferenceKeys`, this sort of alignment is probably better solved with [alignment guides](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/).